# Segmentation fault using Shell Builtins using switch

Tags: c

I'm working on a Shell replica for my school project. As you may know, a Shell is a command interpreter and it runs on an infinite loop, then you fork() and run the commands on a child process which terminates and goes back to the parent (loop) waiting for another command to be entered. This is different with builtins (`cd`, `exit`, etc...); you need to run them on the parent process if you want any changes. So I'm using a `switch` statement that detects whether the command entered is built-in or not.

Here's my function that checks beforehand:

```
 int hsh_execute(char **args)
 {
       int i = 0, check;
       char *builtin_str[] = {
               "cd",
               "help",
               "exit"
       };

       for (i = 0; builtin_str[i]; i++)
       {
                if (strcmp(builtin_str[i], args[0]) == 0)
                        break;
       }
       switch (i)
       {
              case 0:
                       hsh_cd(args);
                       break;
                case 1:
                       hsh_help();
                       break;
                case 2:
                       hsh_exit();
                       break;
                default:
                       launch_child(args);
                        break;
        }
        return (1);
}
```

My `launch_child(args)` function is the one that runs after `fork()` in the `default` case after discarding all the builtins. But it gives me segmentation fault. I have the same program but with an array of pointers to functions and it works flawlessly, but I really want to make this `switch` work as well.

Here's my `main()` function if that helps:

```
int main(void)
{
       char *line = NULL, **args = NULL;
       int status;

       do {
                write(1, "$ ", 2);
                line = read_line();
                args = tokenize(line);
                status = hsh_execute(args);
                free(line);
                free(args);
        }
        while (status);
        return (0);
}
```

I hope someone understands my problem, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Close vote? Really? Even if you can't find the problem, OP has a reasonable claim of having done bisection right quote: "I have the same program but with an array of pointers to functions and it works flawlessly, but I really want to make this Switch work as well." Fill in stubs for the missing functions and it's a good bet you get the same crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing your list terminator.

```
        char *builtin_str[] = {
                "cd",
                "help",
                "exit",
                NULL
        };
```

The statement on the next line

```
        for (i = 0; builtin_str[i]; i++)
```

doesn't find the end and picks up some non pointers to pass to `strcmp` for a crash. With this loop, putting a `NULL` as the list item in the list is the way to end it.